# Android 3G Tethering

Tags: android, 3g, tethering, access-point, wimax

For a research project, I must work on the design of 3G/WiMAX Access Point (AP) protocols. I have access to 2 Android smartphones.

Android devices can become WiFi hotspots for other devices, allowing WiFi tethering.

In this scheme, does the Android devices behave like a regular WiFi AP (like the one present in your home WLAN) or does it just forward the connection from the AP it is connected to ?

Similarily, is there a way of turning one of my smartphone into a 3G/WiMAX AP, so that the other can connect to it as if it was a 3G/WiMAX tower ? If so, can you provide some references and resources that would allow to do that ?

EDIT:

Ok so the keyword is "**AP mode**", it is a mode available in some Wireless Network Drivers like ath9k, bcm but is absent from most others. It is used to turn the device into an AP (or more accurately a simulated one).

The answer of the first question **"Does it behave like an AP?"** is **Yes**: the Android device can behave exactly like an AP (management frames, ack, etc.) AND internaly it forwards the connection from the real AP.

The answer to the second question **"Can we turn it on ?"** is **"It depends on your wireless driver, and thus on your wireless card"**. Some drivers (ath9k, bcmon) have the options, some others don't. You will have to search for your network card name and check it out.

In my case, I wanted to change the behaviour of on AP (by modifying the driver / kernel), but found out that my driver is a firmware (and proprietary). I ended up adding an USB Wifi adapter that is supported by the driver ath9k (open-source driver for Atheros chipsets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like a 'regular' AP, taking into account that both Android and WiFi are constantly evolving and hence the definition of regular may be a moving target.

You can test the behaviour by finding a location with no 2G/3G/4G etc coverage and run a local network with your phone as the AP for multiple devices. An long distance flight for example (where devices on flight laws allow...).

For testing I am not aware of any free or open source 3G network elements yet, but there are some 2G open source projects it might be worth you looking at:

- http://openbsc.osmocom.org/trac/
- http://openbts.org

The former has definitely mentioned plans for an open RNC (3G access point) but it is not clear what stage these are at.

Turning a smartphone into a 3G access point (RNC) is definitely not going to be just a matter of developing an app. Given the hardware is probably all there, I am sure it is technically possible if you are prepared to write a lot of low level software, but I think you would probably find it much easier to look at the approaches the above project have taken and see what their plans are for 3G.